# Strip < Character from XML content

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I have an XML Document where it contains data with `<` character.

```
<Tunings>
    <Notes>Norm <150 mg/dl</Notes>
</Tunings>
```

The code I am using is:

```
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strFile);
string strData = objReader.ReadToEnd();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

// Here I want to strip those characters from "strData"

doc.LoadXml(strData);
```

So it gives error:

> Name cannot begin with the '1' character, hexadecimal value 0x31.

So is there a way to strip those characters from XML before Load calls.?

Comment: Do you have access to the code that creates the XML file?

Comment: "I have an XML Document" -- no, you don't. `<150` is not a valid XML tag. Instead of fixing the reader, check if you can fix the generator of the file. Otherwise you're pretty much stuck with implementing your own parser for this XML-like-but-not-quite file format.

Comment: Yes..I can fix that at the time of creation but now I want the files to import even if it contains those invalid characters.

Comment: The XmlException gives you the line number and position of the error. You could check if the exception is a 'Name cannot begin with the X character' error and, if yes, remember the position, open the file with a text reader, replace the invalid character, and try loading it into an XmlDocument again.

Comment: How do you expect to tell the difference between valid and invalid `<` characters? Are all the bad ones followed by numbers?

Comment: @VishalSuthar - "I can fix that at the time of creation but now I want the files to import even if it contains those invalid characters."  If you can control the output (creation) of the XML, I think it would be far better to focus on that, rather than trying to handle invalid XML when you're parsing it.  If you absolutely need to have the `<` in there, wrap that element's content in a CDATA tag XML parsers won't choke on it.

Comment: @Vishal This is what you get for building XML from concatenating strings. A word of warning: If the fix you have in mind goes something like "*I'll just string-replace `<` with `&lt;` before I output it"* then you've fixed nothing. Use a proper API (e.g. `XmlDocument` or `XmlWriter`).

Answer (score 0):

If this is only occurring in the `<Notes>` section, I'd recommend you modify the creation of the XML file to use a CDATA tag to contain the text in Notes, like this:

```
<Notes><![CDATA[Norm <150 mg/dl]]></Notes>
```

The CDATA tag tells XML parsers to not parse the characters between the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`.  This allows you have characters in your XML that would otherwise break the parsing.

You can use the CDATA tag for any situation where you know (or have reasonable expectations) of special characters in that data.

Trying to handle special characters at parsing time (without the CDATA) will be more labor intensive (and frustrating) than simply fixing the creation of the XML in the first place, IMO.  Plus, "Norm <150 mg/dl" is *not* the same thing as "Norm 150 mg/dl", and that distinction might be important for whoever needs that information.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state, you do not have an XML document.  If you know that the only way that these documents deviate from legal XML is as in your example, you could run the file through a regular expression and replace `<(?:\d)` with `&amp;`.  This will find the `<` adjacent to a number and properly encode it.